# Freya cursor not moving

Tags: system

The cursor works on Windows but stops when I boot up elementary. I have seen other people have the same problem after they suspend their system but none of the solutions worked for me

I would appreciate the help

Answer (score 1):

It's a well-known bug on Freya.

I couldn't fix that, but pressing CTRL+ALT+F1 (you enter the CLI interface) and then CTRL+ALT+F7 (to enter again the GUI) helps.

The problem with cursor appears also after locking and hibernating my computer.

I recommend Loki - I didn't experience any bugs like that. :)

Answer (score 1):

It's a known bug. The only way I could fix it was installing Loki. If you don't want to, you can restore the cursor by following this steps:

- Press Ctrl + Alt + F1
- Press Ctrl + Alt + F7

You should now have the cursor restored and working, and yes, you have to do this every time it happens